# Navigation concept in Roku

Tags: xml, roku, brightscript

I am facing some issue in screen navigation in Roku Brightscript. Please, anyone, help me how I can manage 5-6 screen in my Roku project. I want to navigate from 1 to 2 screen and also want to back from that screen. This is some major issue I have for the last 6 month. I am not able to do it. Some help from your side helps me to understand.

Currently, I have tried by following below procedure

1-if I want to go to 2 screens then I will do below part

```
   m.top.AppendChild(m.secondscreen)
   m.secondscreen.setFocus(true)
   m.secondscreen.visible="true"
```

2- when I click back then in a second-screen back key I will return it false So that it comes to 1st screen back and here I will just do this

```
   m.secondscreen.setFocus(false)
   m.secondscreen.visible="false"
   return true
```

Here it will come to the 1st screen. So like this, I will go to all pages. But I know this is not the exact process in Roku. So I have faced many difficulties by doing this.and I am not able to move from 5 screens to 1 screen by following the above procedure
So anyone let me understand with some example if you have.it will be grateful to you

Answer (score 4):

I assume your m.secondscreen is a "roSGScreen" component and if so, you are correct that you are incorrect.  A Roku scenegraph application should only have one "roSGScreen" created ever.

The concept of "screen" is confusing, because you can create many components that could be thought of as "screens" when they're actually just views.  Your one and only scene should control the active views (subcomponents, not roSGScreens) and can attach / detach or show / hide the subcomponents as needed based on user action.

Technically speaking, I'm pretty certain that you want to manage 5 views, not 5 screens.

I suggest spending some time with the example application from the SDK docs tutorial to learn about this more.

Comment: Are you saying there is no built-in good way (or no best practice) to transition between scenes? In many other dev sdks we push/pop view controllers, navigation to/back from pages etc. Is there no such notion? Should we think of a scene as a one-thing and only manipulate the views inside of that one?

Comment: @Jonny Your last statement is correct. As Joe T mentioned, the best practice is having a `Scene` component where you manage screens/pages/views (whatever you want to call them), with your own navigation logic. These views would usually extend the `Group` component and have their own components structure.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the view stack component provided by Roku on some published channels.

I encourage you to use it, it will make easier the screen handling.

Please see [Github](https://github.com/rokudev/SceneGraphDeveloperExtensions#component-controller) [Sample](https://github.com/rokudev/SceneGraphDeveloperExtensions/blob/master/documentation/3-ViewStack_Guide.md) [Docs](https://sdkdocs-archive.roku.com/Using-ViewStack_5443630.html).

Probably at first, the setup could be painful but definitely, it's more scalable as your applications keep growing.

To show a screen, you call it like this:

```
viewOne = CreateObject("roSGNode", "customScreen")
m.top.ComponentController.CallFunc("show", {
  view: viewOne
})
```

To close your screen manually, you just need to change a property "close" to true.

```
viewOne.close = true
```

You can keep calling the show method and it will append all those views on the stack.

You also gain some functionality by letting the component controller handle your screen stack:

• **currentView** - Links to the view that is currently shown by ViewStack (This view represents the view that is shown by ViewStack.

• **allowCloseChannelOnLastView** - If true, the channel closes when the back button is pressed or if the previous view set the view's close field to true

• **allowCloseLastViewOnBack** - If true, the current view is closed, and the user can open another view through the new view's wasClosed callback

***Notice that***
*If another view without using ViewStack is shown, it wouldn't be reflected on the stack or could be accessed by the current view reference)*

===============UPDATE==========

With the sample code of the original question (assuming you made the setup of the viewstack):

```
' To show the second screen
m.top.ComponentController.CallFunc("show", {
      view: m.secondView
})

' to show another view on top.
m.thirdView = CreateObject("roSGNode", "thirdView")
m.top.ComponentController.CallFunc("show", {
      view: m.thirdView
})
' to close third screen and go back to second screen
m.thirdView.close = true
```

Comment: you perform any example on this?

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya, a good place to start is with the hello world app [link](https://github.com/rokudev/SceneGraphDeveloperExtensions/tree/master/samples/1_Setup+and+HelloWorld), with that you'll have the setup ready. 

On your MainScene.brs, override the "show" method to display your first screen as pointed on the response.




`screenOne = CreateObject("roSGNode", "customScreen")
m.top.ComponentController.CallFunc("show", {
  view: screenOne
})`

Comment: Thank you for your reply But still, I'm Confused.

Comment: No worries, can you be more specific about why are you confused? @NikunjChaklasiya

Comment: I think you know the first file always create with roSGScreen then second for roSGNode so here the show function write is a First screen code or second screen code.

Comment: here the custom screen creates a second screen so show function writes for second screen code or first screen code every time confusion over here.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya just updated my response, hopefully, it's clear now.

Comment: As others pointed out, usually apps have one scene and within that scene you have the logics for the views.
https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/scenegraph-nodes.md

Comment: Thank you I Cleard now. here my first screen code write in main.brs `screen = CreateObject("roSGScreen")     
  m.port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
 ' m.st = CreateObject("roSystemTime") 
  screen.setMessagePort(m.port)
  scene = screen.CreateScene("WisePanel") `

Comment: here second screen code second .brs file write `screenOne = CreateObject("roSGNode", "customScreen") m.top.ComponentController.CallFunc("show", { view: screenOne })` It is correct?

Comment: Awesome! so If you followed the GitHub project, your wisePanel scene must extend from "BaseScene" right? on your WisePanel.brs there should be a function called "show", in that function you should be able the call the "show" function from the componentController.

Comment: Hey, bro sry But Still It's Not Working. I'm trying to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374718/how-to-access-another-file-label-using-a-brightscript this thing.

Comment: I try to open another scene but every time gave the show function error like this `Interface not a member of BrightScript Component (runtime error &hf3)`

Answer (score 0):

Add one thing in your code :

`m.secondscreen.close = true
return true`

Roku navigation first close screen is required. After the first screen is closed then the second screen will open. it's definitely work.

Comment: Ya but my process is wrong of doing this thing. could you please elaborate on how I should handle back. how you handle this

Comment: But if i switch from 5th screen to 2nd screen then how i can do this.

Comment: Here if i append that screen then it will through errors

Comment: Roku support back button automatic. But its handle custom. first close 1st screen after that open 2nd screen. first write `m.firstscreen.setFocus(true) m.firstscreen.visible="true" m.firstscreen.close="true" m.secondscreen.setFocus(true) m.secondscreen.visible="true" i hope this is helpful.

Comment: it's every back key press you require open screen is closed. after that open next screen. check it in your code

Comment: First you create a global variable in main.brs m.global = screen.getGlobalNode() like these

Comment: Now you use the XML <field id="screensecond" type="string" onChange = "screensecond"/> id is use m.global .screenfirst and onchange write the screen function name

Comment: here field write in both the xml screenfirst and screensecond

Comment: and call to the firstscreen in a button event

Comment: hey please send me the code by upload in your drive.its easy for me also

Comment: these code for button click event manage gschoppe in a github in following link :

Comment: There is nothing which i want here

Comment: sry, bro its some time to write code. it's for 3 to 4 days. Now it's not available.

Comment: ohk lets party. which way you apply.

Comment: I got the same issue on this. I created a one Login screen and navigate to my home screen but it does not find out. please help me out.

Comment: hii Bishal plz you add the answer for this question for knowledge purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I thought another way to navigate. simply add all widget or component add in a single group and apply Hide/show concept in ROKU. Its work for me to change the screen. ROKU doesn't provide any specific navigation.